# IIS on Windows 10. Server Error 503

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-10, http-status-code-503, server-error

I have Windows 10 and I want to run IIS. 
I have activeted all features for it, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYEU2.jpg).
Then I type "localhost" in the browser and I take

"HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable."

In some forums they say to control the log HTTP Error file, so I do, but it is empty.

Then I go to the ISS manager to see for [configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVQ81.jpg).

How can I resolve this *"Il server è configurato per l'uso dell'autenticazione pass-through con un account predefinito per accedere al percorso fisico specificato. Tuttavia, Gestione IIS non può verificare se l'account predefinito ha l'accesso. Verificare che l'identità del pool di applicazioni abbia l'accesso in lettura al percorso fisico. Se questo server è aggiunto a un dominio e l'identità del pool di applicazioni è NetworkService o LocalSystem, verificare che '*< dominio>\< nome_computer>$*' abbia l'accesso in lettura al percorso fisico, quindi riprovare queste impostazioni."*?

I understand that I have to verify if the identity of the App pool has the reading access to the physical path. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: In my case, I had an app pool name that ended with a dot ("."). After deleting and creating a new app pool with a name that does _not_ end with a dot, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 17):

With IIS, the error message "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable." typically means the site itself is running but the application pool associated with the site is stopped. Check the application pool and start it if is stopped.

If you see the application pool stopping again after you request the page, check your Event Viewer for error entries explaining why it stopped the pool.

Comment: Event Viewer says that there's a problem with user authentication

Comment: It didn't help me on Windows Pro10 and IIS 10. IIS is insalled and IIS manager shows that DefaultApp pool is started. But even Default Web Site returns page with 503 error.

Comment: What do you see in the Event Viewer? Also, verify Default Web Site is using DefaultApp pool regarding your scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Just update the credentials in Application pool. You can update this by going to IIS manager=>Application Pools=> your pool name=>Right click then Advance Settings =>Identity=> custom  and update the username and password that may help.